# How to iterate between directories in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I want to convert images from `.img` to `.nii.gz` using the function `fslchfiletype`.

These images are stored in `Controls` and `Patients` folders, each one of this folders have several folders belonging to each one of the individuals, like `C01, C02,` , etc. Specifically, each one of the individuals has the `.img` files inside a folder called `rs_roi`, which is inside another folder called `ROIS2`. This is what I have:

```
DIR="/media/Roy"; cd "$DIR/Analysis"
for group in Controls Patients; do
    for case in $group; do
        mkdir $DIR/Analysis/$group/$case/Cortical_masks 
                
        for file in $DIR/Analysis/$group/$case/ROIS2/rs_roi/.img; do
        fslchfiletype NIFTI_GZ "$file"
        done;
    done;
done;
```

Notice how I also want to create a `folder` called `Cortiical_maks` inside each and one of the individuals.

This gives me the next error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ´media/Roy/Analysis/Controls/Controls/Cortical_masks´: No such file or directory.
Cannot open volume media/Roy/Analysis/Controls/Controls/ROIS2/rs_roi/ for reading!
mkdir: cannot create directory ´media/Roy/Analysis/Patients/Patients/Cortical_masks´: No such file or directory.
Cannot open volume media/Roy/Analysis/Patients/Patients/ROIS2/rs_roi/ for reading!
```

It´s iterating two times the `Controls Patients` folder: `Control/Control`. Maybe the problem is here `for case in $group; do`? Thx

Comment: DON'T use the `script` tag. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. It's no better than adding `code` as a tag. That tag is just noise, it was deleted in the past and will be deleted very soon again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your directory name assigned to a variable, you have to glob the directory to get its contents. Otherwise, as you saw, `$group` is not expanded, and you're only looping over that single term itself.

You might also like to check that each entry is indeed a directory before you traverse into it.

```
for case in $group/*; do
    [ -d $case ] || continue
    mkdir $DIR/Analysis/$group/$case/Cortical_masks 
            
    for file in $DIR/Analysis/$group/$case/ROIS2/rs_roi/.img; do
    fslchfiletype NIFTI_GZ "$file"
    done;
done;
```

You should probably also quote your variables in more places, unless you are sure they don't need quoting. I always lint my scripts with [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to get that kind of advice.

Comment: Thx for the answer, it´s been useful. However bash was still iterating two times over `$group`,  so I deleted it in both path functions. I wrote an answer with a script that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small change to @Noah answer, this script works fine:

```
for group in Controls Patients; do
    for case in $group/*; do
        [ -d $case ] || continue
        mkdir $DIR/Analysis/$case/Cortical_masks 
            
        for file in $DIR/Analysis/$case/ROIS2/rs_roi/*.img; do
        fslchfiletype NIFTI_GZ "$file"
        done;
    done;
done;
```

I deleted `$group` in both paths, and added `*` in `*.img` which i forgot.

Comment: [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)